# Identify maven dependency from list of jars

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I am trying to convert my existing web app project into maven. I have a bunch of jars in my project manually downloaded and kept in a directory. While converting to maven, I need the name of group id and artifact id of these jars so that I can mention it in pom.xml.

Is there any other way than manually searching for each jar name in mvnrepository.com?

Comment: When I had this kind of problem, I computed the checksums of all JARs and looked them up on MavenCentral. This gave me some matches. The rest was manual work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're slightly out of luck. There might be a chance that some of the jars contain the information you're looking for under

```
META-INF/maven/<groupId>/<artifactId>/pom.properties
```

But other than that, @JFabianMeier is right, it's manual labor. And please be aware that Maven uses *transitive dependencies* that may affect your classpath differently than when you specify the jars from a directory.

You might have to add exclusions to your POM's transitive dependencies to get the classpath as you want it.